# d3js chord diagram multilevel - level, sublevel, subsublevel

Tags: javascript, d3.js, sunburst-diagram, chord-diagram

i want to help me in a small personal project with some ideas or documentations.
I want to use [d3.js](http://d3js.org) to create a [chord diagram](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1046712) with level and sub-levels (a hierarchy).

All examples explain only one level.

What i want i think is a combination of [sunburst](http://strongriley.github.io/d3/ex/sunburst.html), but with hierarchy from edge to center  and in center chord diagrams.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How would this even look for a "chord" that needs to go from, say, the east side of the outer circle to the west side of the inner?  This seems difficult to comprehend visually.

Comment: visual is very simple. From out to in: the first circle have 5 groups and every group have subgroups and every subgroups have elements. An element can exist on other group or subgroup of another groups like [Circos](http://circos.ca)

Comment: So you would need to combine the sunburst and chord layouts for this. AFAIK this hasn't been done, but sounds like an interesting project.

Comment: Yes. Sunburst or a donut chart with sublevels. Now i stil read d3.js documentation and test.